# System.InvalidCastException in calling CLR stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, clrstoredprocedure

I am trying to debug a CLR stored procedure in Visual Studio 2012. When I call it, this error occurs and the CLR stored procedure is not getting called:

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "CalculateResultByUser": 
System.InvalidCastException: No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32' al tipo 'System.IConvertible'.
System.InvalidCastException: 
   en System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)
   en StoredProcedures.CalculateResultByUser(SqlInt32 idUsuario, SqlDateTime fechaInicio, SqlDateTime fechaFin)
```

This is the CLR stored procedure definition:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void CalculateResultByUser(SqlInt32 idUsuario, SqlDateTime fechaInicio, SqlDateTime fechaFin)
{
}
```

And this is how I am trying to call it:

```
EXEC CalculateResultByUser  5, '2014-07-26 00:00:00', '2014-07-26 23:59:59'
```

Any help please?
Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Can you translate the error message? most of us regular to read them in English... I can translate myself... I can even guess that the message is saying that `SqlInt32` isn't implements `IConvertible`. But I think it's your responsibility, as well of showing us the code of `CalculateResultByUser` (or a simplified version).

Comment: I haven't shown more detail because the stored procedure is not being called actually.That is the difficulty.. I cannot debug it.

Comment: If it isn't being called, I would guess that what is sent to the method is in fact `Int32` (not `SqlInt32`), and that the runtime is trying to convert `Int32` (the argument) to `SqlInt32` (the parameter), but fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure enough, [SqlInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't appear to implement [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I am guessing that somewhere in your stored procedure you are calling [Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to extract the integer value from your SqlInt32 - which will not work because this struct does not implement this interface.

It does have an [explicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7dd6hyb2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    int id = (idUsuario.IsNull ? -1 : (int)idUsuario);
```

Or alternatively

```
    int? nId = (idUsuario.IsNull ? (int ?)null : (int)idUsuario);
```

Can you use that?

Comment: Stored procedure is not being called, so that the problem is not in the body, but in the calling.I realized of that because I have placed a breakpoint in the very beginning of the body and never get reached. when I debug, the execution stopped at the SQL file I have in my project, which has the EXEC instruction.When I press F11 to continue execution, immediately shows that error.

Comment: Suggestions to see where the exception is thrown: use the [Exception Assistant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/197c1fsc.aspx) to break when a System.InvalidCastException is thrown; [Enable stepping into properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667388%28v=vs.90%29.aspx); [Enable unmanaged debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tdw0c6sf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks... the problem was what you wrote in your post. I had: "int userId = idUsuario". Since idUsuario will never be null, I changed it to: "int userId = idUsuario.Value" and it worked. The problem I could not debug was because I have not checked "Allow SQL/CLR Debugging" in SQL Server object explorer. Regards.